# Particles passing through each other

Tags: optimization, simulation, collision, particles

I am writing a code to simulate particle movement. (currently  2D soon 3D hopefully)
The thing is, if I use a relatively large timestep particles end up passing through each other.

Do you have any suggestion that would allow me to correct that without using a really small step?
(it is in C++ if that makes much difference).

Comment: Please consider add your code in order to see what is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [use of timestep to advance the clock introduces model artifacts](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc11papers/218.pdf) which can destroy the model validity, as is happening in your case. Use discrete event scheduling instead. This [paper from Winter Simulation Conference 2005](http://informs-sim.org/wsc05papers/118.pdf) describes how to implement movement in a discrete event framework. Your model will not only be more accurate, it will probably run much faster as well.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i will know implement it and see if the expense outweighs the costs or not :-)

Answer (score 1):

So you will have to do some sort of [collision detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) to see if two objects would collide.

Depending on your data structure the detection could take many forms. If you just have a list of points you would have to check all against each other in N^2 each step for the particle (adding the movement vector to create a larger spacial foot print). This could be done by the [GJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm) algorithm.

Using some spacial data structure could reduce the complexity by only running the GJK on a pruned set of particles, i.e. no need to check if they impossible could overlap.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i will know implement it and see if the expense outweighs the costs or not :-)